# Jade : Click event handler not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, pug

I'm trying to write a functionality for disabling a button based on the number of lists. The front-end code is written in Jade. Here's the flow. From the items list, there is an option for deleting individual item. Whenever i click on delete anchor, a script should check, the number of items. If it is zero, then disable the button. Here's the code sample :

```
    button#savethemebtn.n-e-w-more-button.publish-button.margin-top-none.hint--top(onclick='updateShareModal();', href='#shareModal', role='button btn', data-toggle='modal', data-id='magId', data-hint='Share this Theme.', style="background-color:#cc1235")

     a#delItem(style='cursor:pointer;') // Delete button
         img(src='/assets/img/library/close.png')
```

In the same file i have written a script

```
    script.

     $('#delItem').on('click',function(){
       var items = $('#current-KO-lists').children().length;
       alert(items);
       if(items == 0){
        $('#savethemebtn').prop('disabled',true);
       }
     });
```

When clicking on the delete button, its not firing the ".on" handler. Tried enclosing the handler inside an anonymous function, but it didn't work. Thanks

Major edit : Its not button, its an anchor tag(delItem)

Comment: What is Jquery version

Comment: are there multiple delet button with same id="delItem"?

Comment: @Amit Jquery version 2.1.1

Comment: Is your `$('#delItem') wrapped in a document ready handler?

Comment: @ganaraj No, its not wrapped inside document ready

Comment: Are you creating delItem on runtime

Comment: @sandeshps that is pretty important. You need to ensure that all dom selections happen *after* document ready.

Comment: @Amit No, its a statically created one

Comment: @ganaraj Wrapping inside document.ready doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).on('click','#delItem',function(){
       var items = $('#current-KO-lists').children().length;
       alert(items);
       if(items == 0){
        $('#savethemebtn').prop('disabled',true);
       }
 });
```

Comment: are you using any other plugin that binds click event to delItem?

Comment: No, i'm not using additional plugins

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
$('#delItem').click(function(){
   var items = $('#current-KO-lists').children().length;
   alert(items);
   if(items == 0){
    $('#savethemebtn').prop('disabled',true);
   }
 });
```

Comment: Its means some event deattach the handler

Comment: Just edited the question. The element (delItem) is not a button, its an anchor tag.